# Cassandra only returning a subset of my rows when using varchar

Tags: c++, cassandra, cql3

I have encountered a problem when using Apache Cassandra, in that I have 500k rows of entries in a 4 column table. 3 of the columns make up the compound key and the last one is a help column for indexing so that I can search in between the other ones using greater than or lesser than operators. The 3 components of the compund key are integers, and the help column is a varchar filled with help for all 500k entries. Now, when i use:

```
select count(*) from table where help='help' limit 1kk allow filtering;
```

I should have gotten as result 500k, but I get 36738.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

If the table has for columns: id, column1, column2, help; my query needs to be something similar to:

```
select * from table where column1 > 15 and column1 < 1000 and column2 > 200 and column2 < 10000 and help='help' limit 1kk allow filtering;
```

Also when I created the table, I used PRIMARY KEY(id, column1, column2)

Comment: Just to clarify, you have no index for "help" column, do you?

Comment: What is `1kk`?  That is invalid syntax.  Are you pasting your query verbatim?  Secondly, you should not need `allow filtering` if you have an index.  If you don't have an index your query should not be able to run...

Lastly, if you still see a count mismatch with a syntactically correct query, you're probably running into a bug in Cassandra, which you should report on Cassandra jira (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA). (If you're using an older release, you should try to update first to see if your problem is already fixed)

Comment: Mikhail Of course I have index for help column. It wouldn't allow me to search using help column otherwise. @Daniel 1kk means 1 million. I used 1kk for convenience. The verbatim query is: "select * from table where column1 > 15 and column1 < 1000 and help = 'help' limit 1000000 allow filtering;". If I try to restrict column1 and column2 it gives me an error (that is how compound primary keys work) I believe it is an error.

Comment: Also, I am using cassandra-2.0.5

Comment: I'm sorry, I am confused.  When you say it gives you an error with column restrictions, do you mean that it fails to execute, or are you getting back an incorrect number of rows?

In any event, if you're getting back an incorrect number of rows (and you've ruled out VARCHAR issues like case mismatch, trailing whitespace, non-English or hidden characters and so forth), then it is definitely a bug in Cassandra or your driver.  If you're using CQLSH, then it's in Cassandra.

Comment: If I try to use > or < on the cluster key "column1" and then the same thing on "column2" cassandra returns an error `partition key part column2 cannot be restricted (preceding part key column1 is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)` which I have come to find out that means that you **MUST** have an EQ relation on "column1" in my example.

Comment: @gcstefan123 It might be a bug in Cassandra for sure, but you definitely have to reconsider your data schema. It should be on your read patters (queries). For example "help" could be part of a  key. Try to avoid secondary indexes